# MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans when use adfuller

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzv8k.png)
code(part):
data = data.iloc[24:].fillna(method = 'ffill')

```
ts=data['pm2.5']

ts_log = np.log(ts)

print(np.isnan(ts_log).sum())[enter image description here][1]

from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)
trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid

    bug:
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-0d6bd884b128> in <module>
      
      1 from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
----> 2 decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)
      3 
      4 trend = decomposition.trend

g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    212                 else:
    213                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 214             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    215 
    216         return cast(F, wrapper)
```

g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model,      filt, period, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
129
130     if not np.all(np.isfinite(x)):
131         raise ValueError("This function does not handle missing values")
132     if model.startswith('m'):
133         if np.any(x <= 0):

ValueError: This function does not handle missing values

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6nNW.pngenter image description here
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3veYu.png)

```
FULL CODE
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
# pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()


data = pd.read_csv('E:/硕士开题/数据/美国驻北京大使馆10-14/PRSA_data_2010.1.1-2014.12.31.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) #显示所有列
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False) #数据超过总宽度后，是否折叠显示


# In[2]:


data = data.iloc[24:].fillna(method = 'ffill')

import datetime
data['Time'] = data.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(year=x['year'],month =x['month'],day = x['day'],hour = x['hour']),axis = 1) #把年月日小时合并为一列

data.drop(columns=['No', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'], inplace=True)
data = data.set_index('Time')
data.head()


# In[3]:


# data.to_csv('E:/aaaa.csv')
plt.figure(figsize=(24,10))
plt.plot(data['pm2.5'])


plt.show()


# In[4]:


ts=data['pm2.5']

ts.head()
_index = ts.index
_index


# In[5]:


#归一化
import sklearn.preprocessing as preprocessing
s1 = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
s2 = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

ts_array = ts.values
ts = ts_array.reshape(len(ts),1)
ts = s2.fit_transform(ts)


ts = ts.reshape(len(ts))

ts = pd.Series(ts,index=_index)

ts = pd.DataFrame(ts)

ts.head()

# pd.DataFrame(ts).columns.values.tolist()


# In[6]:


#检查平稳性
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
def test_stationarity(timeseries):
    
    #Determing rolling statistics
    rolmean = timeseries.rolling(window=12).mean()
    rolstd = timeseries.rolling(window=12).std()

    #Plot rolling statistics:
    orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color='blue',label='Original')
    mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
    std = plt.plot(rolstd, color='black', label = 'Rolling Std')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation')
    plt.show(block=False)
    
    #Perform Dickey-Fuller test:
    print('Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:')
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
    print(dfoutput)


# In[7]:


test_stationarity(ts)


# In[18]:


#取对数查看趋势
ts_log = np.log(ts)
ts_log.dropna(inplace = True)
print(np.isnan(ts_log).sum())
# test_stationarity(ts_log)
plt.plot(ts_log)
ts_log.info()


# In[9]:


#12项指数加权移动平均
expwighted_avg = pd.DataFrame.ewm(ts_log,halflife = 12).mean()
plt.plot(ts_log)
plt.plot(expwighted_avg,color ='red')


# In[10]:


ts_log_ewma_diff = ts_log - expwighted_avg #把移动平均从原始时间序列中减去

test_stationarity(ts_log_ewma_diff) #再检查平稳性


# In[11]:


#消除季节性和趋势
#使用一次偏移进行差异化
ts_log_diff = ts_log - ts_log.shift()
plt.plot(ts_log_diff)


# In[12]:


ts_log_diff.dropna(inplace = True)

test_stationarity(ts_log_diff)


# In[13]:


#分离趋势季节误差
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log,period = 1)

trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid

plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(ts_log, label='Original')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(412)
plt.plot(trend, label='Trend')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(413)
plt.plot(seasonal,label='Seasonality')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(414)
plt.plot(residual, label='Residuals')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.tight_layout()


# In[14]:


#差分后 绘制TS的ACF和PACF图
#ACF and PACF plots:
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf

lag_acf = acf(ts_log_diff, nlags=20)
lag_pacf = pacf(ts_log_diff, nlags=20, method='ols')


# In[15]:


#Plot ACF: 
plt.subplot(121) 
plt.plot(lag_acf)
plt.axhline(y=0,linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(ts_log_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(ts_log_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.title('Autocorrelation Function')

#Plot PACF:
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(lag_pacf)
plt.axhline(y=0,linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(ts_log_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(ts_log_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.title('Partial Autocorrelation Function')
plt.tight_layout()


# In[16]:


# ts_log.reset_index(drop=True)
print(np.isnan(ts_log).sum())


# In[17]:


from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

model = ARIMA(ts_log, order=(2, 1, 2))  
results_ARIMA = model.fit(disp=-1)  
plt.plot(ts_log_diff)
plt.plot(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues, color='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ARIMA.fittedvalues-ts_log_diff)**2))


# In[ ]:


# #恢复到原始比例
# predictions_ARIMA_diff = pd.Series(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues, copy=True)
# predictions_ARIMA_diff.head()

# predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum = predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum()
# predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum.head()

# predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(ts_log.iloc[0], index=ts_log.index)
# predictions_ARIMA_log = predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum,fill_value=0)
# predictions_ARIMA_log.head()


# predictions_ARIMA = np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)
# plt.plot(ts)
# plt.plot(predictions_ARIMA)
# plt.title('RMSE: %.4f'% np.sqrt(sum((predictions_ARIMA - ts)**2)/len(ts)))


# In[ ]:





# In[ ]:
```

IF anyone can help me,i would be gratful.the data i can transport to you

Comment: Hi. Please post the result of `ts_log.info()`

Comment: `ffill` won't remove `NaN`s at the start of the sample.  You might need to call `bfill` for these, or just `fillna`.

Comment: @KevinS Thanks,The first few lines have no Nan after 24 lines

Comment: @MaxPierini thanks,the result of ts_log.info() is                                                      dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 16703 entries, 2010-01-02 00:00:00 to 2014-12-30 00:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   0       16703 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 261.0 KB

Comment: I post a new imgae,I guess there is something wrong in ts_log. the picture PACF is werid

Comment: I am a newcomer,so i don't know how to post a few image

Comment: what my aim is to predict  concentration of pm2.5 hourly. So i want to separate the factor of trend and season in the data to predict preciser in the model of ARIMA